ValueError: A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function
Well, I've had enough of this problem, I'm trying to use a Transformer XL model for a PPO task (at the moment a simplified version of pokemon, but that's not relevant).
here is the code:

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_models as tfm
# Define model parameters
vocab_size = 56 # Vocabulary size
max_length = 23 # Maximum length of the sequence
embedding_dim = 12 # Embedding dimension
num_attention_heads = 4 # Number of attention heads
hidden_size = 512
head_size=4
initializer='glorot_uniform' # Hidden size
inner_size = 2048 # Internal feed-forward network size
dropout_rate = 0.2 # Dropout rate
attention_dropout_rate = 0.1 # attention dropout rate
num_layers=23

# Create the model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_length,))
x=tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)(inputs)
# Add the TransformerXL block
transformer_block = tfm.nlp.layers.TransformerXL(
    vocab_size,
    layer_number,
    occulto_size,
    number_heads_attention,
    head_size,
    inside_size,
    dropout_rate,
    attention_dropout_rate,
    initializer,
    two_stream=False,
    tie_attention_biases=False,
    memory_length=23,
    reuse_length=23,
    inner_activation='relu'
)

# Instead of converting 'x' to a TensorFlow Tensor directly,
# pass it as is to the TransformerXL layer.
# The layer will handle the necessary conversions internally.


# Pass the relative position encoding to TransformerXL
x = transformer_block(x)


# Add an output layer
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)
# Define the final model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Model summary
model.summary()

and this gives me an error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last).
 in <line: 43>()
41
42 # Pass relative position encoding to TransformerXL.
---> 43 x = transformer_block(x)
44
45
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
94 bound_signature = None
95 try:
---> 96 return fn(*args, **kwargs).
97 except Exception as e:
98 if hasattr(e, “_keras_call_info_injected”):
TypeError: TransformerXL.call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'relative_position_encoding'.
Trying to pass another argument (Imput, embeding) causes the error: ValueError: A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when building Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. It can only be used as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the keras.layers and keras.operations namespaces).
I don't know why this is happening.
